# Uso de Thread em PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer uso de `threads` em PHP porem não esta funcionando o processo de "instalação". Vou descrever o que estou fazendo.

ERRO QUE OBTENHO:

> Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in.

1.Versão do meu php. *OBS.Uso o WAMP*

```
versão 7.0.10
```

2.Estou baixando os arquivos desse site

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/0.0.44/

pra ser mais exato este que estou baixando

```
php_pthreads-0.0.44-5.3-ts-vc9-x86
```

3.Estou fazendo o que é indicado na documentação.

3.1 Extrair o `.zip` -

Mova `php_pthreads.dll` para o diretório `bin\php\ext\`

Mova `pthreadVC2.dll` para o diretório `bin\php\`.

Mova `pthreadVC2.dll` para o diretório `bin\apache\bin`.

Mova `pthreadVC2.dll` para o diretório `C:\windows\system32`.

3.2 Abra php \ php.ini e adicione

Extension = php_pthreads.dll

4.Esses são os caminhos que estou instalando.

4.1.Estou movendo o arquivo php_pthreads.dll para

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext
```

4.2. Estou movendo o arquivo `pthreadVC2.dll` para

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10
```

4.3 Estou movendo o arquivo `pthreadVC2.dll` para

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin
```

4.4 Estou movendo o arquivo `pthreadVC2.dll` para

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

5.Por ultimo

estou colocando o nome

```
Extension = php_pthreads.dll
```

no arquivo `ini`

Comment: O seu PHP é x64 ou x86? Ele foi compilado no VC9 ou no VC11 ou outro? Olhe no `<?php phpinfo();` para saber estes detalhes. Sendo php7 duvido muito que foi compilado no MSVC9

Comment: Você está usando o comando USE no inicio do arquivo?
Ex.: > <?php
> > USE Thread;
> > namespace app\MyClass;
> > class MyClass extends Thread {
> //...
> } ?>

Comment: Bem, Eu uso o pacote do XAMP que contem a versao do php 7.0.10.Fiz todos os procedimentos mas o XAMP nao esta reconhecendo a versao do pthreads que instalei que é 3.1.6-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando instalar a versão não compatível com o php instalado atualmente. Pelo que reparei a versão utilizada é:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10
```

E você está tentando instalar uma versão da biblioteca para o php 5.3.x.
Para as versões 7.x do php vc precisa da biblioteca pthreads em sua versão 3.x

Verifique no link: [windows pthreads](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/). E instale a versão mais atualizada conforme seu php.

Comment: Olá ,realmente tinha  instalado uma versão anterior! só que, agora que instalei a versão 3.1.6-7.0-ts-vc14-x86 o XAMP não esta reconhecendo. O icon fica na cor laranja, alertando que apenas 1 dos 3 serviços esta funcionando.